# Python: week number in each quarter from date pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

I'm trying to get a week number in each quarter (1-13) based on a date.

as an example: '2016-12-29' -> 13

Is there a simple way to get this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here is an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2020-12-12']})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['week_no'] = ((df['date'].dt.isocalendar().week - 1 ) % 13 + 1)
```

First, you format the data as a 'datetime'. Then you look at the week, subtract 1, then take modulo 13, then add back the 1.

Comment: Thanks, using the solution and with data '2020-12-29' i get week_no -> 2... what I want to have for that date is 13

Comment: well, i think the main problem here is that 2020 has more than 52 weeks! 2020-12-29 is week 53 of the year -- so your chosen numbering system doesn't really work.